# How to stop tail -f command through java program?

Tags: java, tail

I'm giving a tail -f command on a log file through java. When a certain string is found, I want to stop following the file and execute the rest of my code. How do I stop it using Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know that this isn't a direct answer to your question, but using a native shell command probably isn't the best way to do this. In addition to the problem that you are experiencing, it makes the code non-portable.

Have a look at Apache's 'Tailer' class - see  http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html
It has a stop() method.

Answer (score 0):

[`Process.destroy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29) might help.